# is there a way to bulk covert docx files into pdf

Tags: python

Is there a way to covert bulk docx files to PDF ?
I'm doing a mailmerge to generate huge number of letters in word extension and i'm struggling on having the pdf conversion for the same letters.

Comment: https://www.roytuts.com/how-to-convert-docx-to-pdf-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

https://pandoc.org/demos.html - pandoc is a library and a command line tool, and it also has python bindings. Demo 35 - 36 shows using docx as an input file, so I think it would work.

If straight PDF output unavailable (I don't think I've used pandoc in that way), you can also output to LaTeX, which can then be compiled to PDF (using miktex or other latex distributions).